# Unable to import type from npm library

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, npm

For a while now I have been using [vuex-router-sync](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex-router-sync) in my vue projects to keep my vuex store in sync with my routes.

For my newest project I now use Typescript for the first time.

In that context I am trying to import the `State` type interface from the library (which is exported according to the [source code](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex-router-sync/blob/master/src/index.ts#L8)) in the following way:

```
import { Module } from "vuex";
import { State } from "vuex-router-sync";

interface RootState {
  route: State;
}

const initialState = {};

export const processDetails: Module<any, any> = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: initialState,
  getters: {
    processId(_, _2, rootState: RootState): string {
      return rootState.route.params.processId;
    },
  },
};
```

Expectation:
Above code should typecheck without error.

Actual Behaviour:
Typescript throws the following exception:
`Module '"../../node_modules/vuex-router-sync/types"' has no exported member 'State'.`

When I look into the file mentioned in the error it infact only contains the type declaration `SyncOption` which I find confusing since it seems to be exported in the same way as `State` in the module source code linked above.

Therefore I was wondering why `State` does not show up in the types file generated and if I can still import this interface somehow.

Contents of `node_modules/vuex-router-sync/types/index.d.ts`:

```
import { Store } from 'vuex';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

interface SyncOptions {
  moduleName: string;
}

export declare function sync(
  store: Store<any>,
  router: VueRouter,
  options?: SyncOptions
): Function;
```

My tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2020",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": ["webpack-env", "jest"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost"]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: Could it be that you are performing a named import on a default export? Try removing the curly braces in this `import { State } from "vuex-router-sync";`

Comment: Martin said what i was about to say... maybe try import { * as State } from ...

Comment: This does not work unfortunately as it will lead to the error `Cannot use namespace 'State' as type`.
The `State` type interface is not the default export in my understanding (see [module-code](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex-router-sync/blob/master/src/index.ts#L8)).
Also if I replace `State` with `SyncOptions` which is defined using the same syntax in the module the import works. (Unfortunately that is not the type that I want to import though)